# hive: parsing JSON contain \"

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

My JSON Data is:

```
 {
    "content":"{\"type\":3,\"from\":\"home\"}",
    "id":"239",
    "idtype":"0",
    "timestamp":"1547957367281",
    "type":"0"
}
```

I want to get this into a table json_data in the below format:

```
+-------------+  
| from        |  
+-------------+  
| home        |  
+-------------+
```

How do I use the explode function from here to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_replace to remove `\`, also `"` before `{` and after `}` should be removed. Use `get_json_object` or [json_tuple](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple) to extract attributes. Testing it on your data example:

```
select get_json_object(json,'$.content.from') as `from`
from
(
select
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(
'{"content":"{\"type\":3,\"from\":\"home\"}",
    "id":"239",
    "idtype":"0",
    "timestamp":"1547957367281",
    "type":"0"
}'               --original data
,'\\\"','\"')    --replace \" with "
,'\\"\\{','{')   --remove " before {
,'\\}\\"','\\}') --remove " after } --these last two can be combined
as json
)s
;
```

Output:

```
OK
from
home
Time taken: 0.329 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Better check these regexp_replaces one-by-one to be sure it works like expected. Hope you got the idea